# Facing issue with PowerShell.exe arguments

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell module as follows

```
function SkipCheck
{

 [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [boolean] $SkipCheck = $false
    )

    if (!($SkipCheck))
    {
        Write-Host "[WARNING]  Are you sure you want to contine" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Pause
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Output "Skipping "
    }
}
```

and my script is as follows

```
[CmdletBinding(
)]

param(
[boolean] $SkipCheck= $false
)
Import-Module "C:\PowerShell\skipcheck.psm1"
Skipcheck
```

I am executing the script as follows, I am getting the warning message but I can not interact with it

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command 'C:\PowerShell\testskip.ps1`

[image]

When I execute directly by opening the file in ISE I am getting it in different way where I can interact

[image]

So can some one help me, reference link http://www.zerrouki.com/powershell-exe-arguments/

Comment: Use `-File` argument to powershell.exe for running scripts.  `-Command` is used if the script is a one-liner on the command line.

Comment: `Ryan Bemrose` Still the same issue

Comment: @RyanBemrose: `Pause` is a function that calls `Read-Host`.

Comment: OK when I execute the same in powershell.exe it works fine seems there is a problem with ISE

Comment: I use this code when I need to prompt for a choice to continue https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730939.aspx

Comment: PowerShell ISE does not support interactive console applications, because it does not have real console.